# Noncommutative group and homomorphic image

Tags: group-theory

Can a noncommutative group be homomorphic image of a Z5 group(mod5)?
I presume no, since Z5 group is commutative.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed no. More generally, can you show that the homomorphic image of any abelian group is abelian? (Minor terminology point: "Abelian," rather than "commutative," is usually used when talking about groups.)

HINT: Suppose $(G, +)$ is abelian and $f:(G, +)\rightarrow (H, *)$ is a surjective homomorphism. Let $x, y\in H$; we want to show $x*y=y*x$.

How can we do this? Well, since $f$ is surjective we have $a, b\in G$ such that $f(a)=x$ and $f(b)=y$. (These $a, b$ need not be unique, but no matter.) Now since $G$ is abelian, what do you know about $a+b$ versus $b+a$? What does that tell you about $x*y$ and $y*x$?

Comment: There's a fancy slogan behind this: "homomorphisms preserve equations." Similarly, *substructures* preserve equations (any subgroup of an abelian group is abelain), as do *Cartesian products* (ditto). This theme is taken up seriously by [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra)